# passing a list to x509.SubjectAlternativeName from cryptography

Tags: python, cryptography, certificate, csr

Trying to solve how to pass a list of san names to x509.SubjectAlternativeName
if looking at the dokumentation at https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/tutorial/#determining-certificate-or-certificate-signing-request-key-type
Example bellow from page, how can i paste a list instead?

What i want as final result is to pass CN with some SAN name to a function and then create csr

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
# Generate a CSR
csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder().subject_name(x509.Name([
    # Provide various details about who we are.
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"US"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"California"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, u"San Francisco"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"My Company"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u"mysite.com"),
])).add_extension(
    x509.SubjectAlternativeName([
        # Describe what sites we want this certificate for.
        x509.DNSName(u"mysite.com"),
        x509.DNSName(u"www.mysite.com"),
        x509.DNSName(u"subdomain.mysite.com"),
    ]),
    critical=False,
# Sign the CSR with our private key.
).sign(key, hashes.SHA256())
# Write our CSR out to disk.
with open("path/to/csr.pem", "wb") as f:
    f.write(csr.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM))
```

I have tried the following but iam doing something wrong.

```
    # Generate a CSR with SAN if needed
    number_of_san = len(common_name)
    print(number_of_san)
    san_names = []
    if number_of_san >= 1:
        print("We have som SAN names")
        for san_name in common_name:
            print('x509.DNSName(u"{}")'.format(san_name))
            san_names.append('x509.DNSName(u"{}")'.format(san_name))
    else:
        print("No SAN, only CN")
    print(san_names)
    print(type(san_names))
    csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder().subject_name(x509.Name([
    # Provide various details about who we are.
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"US"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"California"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, u"San Francisco"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"My Company"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u"mysite.com"),
    ])).add_extension(
        x509.SubjectAlternativeName(
            san_names
 
        ),
        critical=False,
        # Sign the CSR with our private key.
    ).sign(key, hashes.SHA256())
    # Write our CSR out to disk.
    with open(common_name + ".csr", "wb") as f:
        f.write(csr.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM))
```

if we look what is in the list off san_names

```
x509.DNSName(u"teknik.something.se")
x509.DNSName(u"moln.something.se")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did solve the problem.
Instead of append my own text i could just use the following code.

```
for san_name in common_name:
    san_names.append(x509.DNSName(san_name))
```

if only i had checked what python3 do with the class in python cli.

```
from cryptography import x509
x509.DNSName(u"mysite.com")
```

Response:

```
DNSName(value='mysite.com')
```